# html5 local storage only returning values on home page, not other pages

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

This is my first time working with localStorage, and I'm trying to store a json object which I am stringify(ing).

On my home page, I use the following code

```
localStorage.setItem("users",JSON.stringify(userList));

alert(localStorage.getItem("users"));

location.href="test2.html";
```

This alert spits out the userlist no problem.

Then on the test2.html, I have

```
var userList=JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("users"));
    alert(userList.toSource());
```

Firebug spits out a 'userlist is null' error.

I've tried using the string 'test' in place of the strigified json object, but no luck. I've also tried removing the JSON.parse and just get the string returned. This also didn't work.

What am I doing wrong??

Comment: Between the home page and the other pages, is the domain name the same?  How about "http" vs. "https"?

Comment: yes, it is all running locally under c:\, and in the same folder, if that should matter. But I'll try running it from localhost and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: Hmm ... well I know that Chrome is really picky about whether local HTML files are all in the same "domain".  Maybe Firefox is picky too. Can you put the pages on some server somewhere and see if that makes a difference?

Comment: Yup, that was it Pointy, thanks... If you post this as an answer I'll accept it and give you the points.

Comment: OK, done!  Thanks.  It's a weird problem but I think once HTML5 storage is really exploited by more real applications, we'll all appreciate the need for security.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Modern browsers have decided that local files ("file://" URLs, in other words) are **not** all to be considered members of a common "domain", at least for some purposes. Chrome seems to be the strictest, but maybe in the HTML5 features Firefox is also as strict.

It kind-of makes sense: if somebody invents some kind of TiddlyWiki-like tool that uses HTML5 storage, you wouldn't want its stuff to be available to some random other HTML file you download for totally unrelated reasons.