# HTML5 session storage or local storage only returning values on home page and values not get persist on the other page

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, session-variables, session-cookies

I am trying to handle session object across page using HTML5 local storage and both `Local Storage` and `Session Storage` values are not persist on the other than home page. What will be the issue?

```
localStorage.setItem("users",JSON.stringify(userlist));
alert(localStorage.getItem("users"));
```

The users object values exist only on my home page and other page it return as `{}` empty value.

Comment: You should choose session or local; they've got different use cases. Perhaps that's an issue. see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5523140/html5-local-storage-vs-session-storage?rq=1#answer-15166867

Comment: A bit more context is necessary. My guess is that you have wrong/no data in `userlist` and save it to the `localStorage`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4684519/html5-local-storage-only-returning-values-on-home-page-not-other-pages?rq=1

Comment: nope. this is my first question about HTML5 storage. If i store it as string or number, i can able to access in other pages, a object is not get persisit in the session storage.

Comment: @Boltkey i have values in the userlist thats why i am able to see the values in the home page and not able to see that in other pages. Also if i have set my sessionStorage with string or numbers, it gets persisit in the other pages but not the object. If i set object, it is available only to the homepage where it gets sets and it is not exist to invoke in other pages. kindly advice.

Comment: when you retrieve your data, you need to parse it out like, so:
JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('users'))

Comment: @james emanon, i have tried with window.localStorage.getItem , but no luck :(

Comment: // Tab 1
var users = { "foo": 3, "bar": 4 }
localStorage.setItem('users', JSON.stringify(users))
JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('users'))
// Object {foo: 3, bar: 4}

// Tab 2
JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('users'))
// Object {foo: 3, bar: 4}

Comment: @Todd, unfortunately this is not working for me when i set and get as an object. It works fine when i set and get as string or number. Do i need to look for storage events?

Comment: you can, but shouldn't have to. open your browser console, paste this, and see what happens:

var users = { "foo": 3, "bar": 4 };
localStorage.setItem('users', JSON.stringify(users));
JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('users'));

Comment: @user5970552 what browser are you using? what is `userlist`? how big is `userlist`? and also, do you open the pages in the same page/tab or on a new page/tab? could you verify that the two pages are in the same domain and using the same protocol?

Answer (score 0):

Please check the domain in both the pages, `for eg setting it in http://dev1.test.com &  getting it in http://dev2.test.com won't work` as local storage is domain specific

Comment: I have double checked, the second page where i am trying to invoke the storage is also on the same domain.